# Сайт для фотоотчетов

Tags: php, javascript, api, drupal, hosting

Как можно реализовать хранение и загрузку фотографий на сайт с возможностью скачивания. Сайт делается на Drupal 8

Comment: Drupal 8 это всё умеет "из коробки".

Comment: Вам нужно настроить права пользователя (кто может загружать изображения) настроить тип нодов, которые эти пользователи смогут создавать и добавить в меню соответствующие ссылки